# Let $A = \{f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x] ~|~ f(0)f(1) \text{~is~even}\}$ prove or disporve $A$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: polynomials, ideals

Let $A = \{f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x] ~|~ f(0)f(1) \text{ is even}\}$ prove or disporve $A$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

$\textbf{my attempt:}$
Apply the ideal test on $A$.
First, notice that $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$.
ideal test (1):
Let $a(x), b(x) \in A$, WTP: $a(x) - b(x) \in A$.
Since, $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then, $a(x), b(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ which means $a(x) - b(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.
Since, $a(x), b(x) \in A$. Then, $a(0)a(1)$ and $b(0)b(1)$ are both even. Which means $a(0)a(1) - b(0)b(1)$ is even.
So, this means $a(0)a(1) - b(0)b(1) \in A$.
ideal test (2):
Let $a(x) \in A$ and $z(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, WTP: $a(x)z(x) \in A$ or $z(x)a(x) \in A$.
Since, $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then, $a(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Which means $a(x)z(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ as well.
Since, $a(x) \in A$. Then, $a(0)a(1)$ is even.
Since, $z(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then, $z(0), z(1) \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Since, $a(0)a(1)$ is even. So, $a(0)a(1)z(0)z(1)$ is even.
So, $a(x)z(x) \in A$ and $z(x)a(x) \in A$ can be proved similarly.
Therefore, we proved that $A$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

$\textbf{Questions:}$
is that my attempt correct and are there anyting to add to make my prove better ?

Comment: What about the sum of $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1-x$?

Comment: Are both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in $A$?  If so, and if $A$ is an ideal, then $f(x)+g(x)$ would be in $A$, so....

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. Well it turns out this question should be disprove not prove. Thanks !

Comment: Note the spot your proof failed is in the first test.  You needed to check whether $$(a(0)-b(0))(a(1)-b(1))$$ is even.  This is not the same as $a(0)a(1)-b(0)b(1)$

Comment: okay, thanks for pointing out. It turn out that I apply the ideal test (1) wrongly where state that $a - b \in A$ whenever $a \in A$ and $b \in A$.